# Inserting date from Access DB into SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, vba, datetime, ms-access-2010

It seemed to be an easy task but I fail and do not find a solution for my problem: I have a local table in Access 2010 with a date/time column and I want to update a column in a SQL Server table with a datatype `date`.

Sending the date/time values direct to the SQL Server table fails, same with converting the date/time column with this VBA function:

```
Function DateForSQL(dteDate) As String
DateForSQL = "'" & Format(CDate(dteDate), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
End Function
```

which gives

```
DateForSQL(Date()) = '2016-01-14'
```

and should work, I assumed.

The update command is this:

```
UPDATE SQL_table 
INNER JOIN local_table ON SQL_table.ID = local_table.ID 
SET SQL_table.DateField = DateForSQL(local_table.DateField)
```

But it fails again in Access with a type conversion error.

Even when changing the SQL Server table column to datetime I get the same error.

Same with sending to SQL a string like '14/01/2016' or '01/14/2016'.

The only thing I could do - eventually - is to change the datetime to text in Access and try again, but this could not be the only solution.

Any help?

Thanks 
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend to use the **ISO-8601** format for your date - which is `YYYYMMDD` (no dashes, nothing) - this works for all regional & language settings in SQL Server.

Next, I'm not sure about Access' SQL syntax, but in SQL Server, your `UPDATE` statement would be to be something like this:

```
UPDATE sql
SET sql.DateField = DateForSQL(local_table.DateField)
FROM local_table local 
INNER JOIN SQL_table sql ON local.ID = sql.ID
```

First `UPDATE`, then `SET`, then `FROM` and `INNER JOIN` ...

Comment: Thks. The Access Syntax is correct, but even changing to ISO-8601 DateForSQL = "'" & Format(CDate(dteDate), "yyyymmdd") & "'" it fails again.
But you guided me the correct way: I found the solution on changing my UPDATE string to .....SET SQL_table.DateFiled= Format(local_table.DateField,"yyyymmdd")

Thandk, the Problem is solved! Michael